# Can I use an Android application project as a library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, module, exoplayer

In particular, I want to use some of the code in [ExoPlayer's demo](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/master/demo) as a library, in addition to the [library module](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/master/library). Is this possible in Android Studio? (I'm a little bit new).

Thanks.

Comment: can you open the demo project and change the project type to 'android library'? just rebuild it to a android library.

Comment: yes its possible recreate the project and tick islibrary in the setup pages

Comment: @JiangYD I don't see any option to do that in Android Studio. File > New > Import Project... > demo > OK   ... then what?

Comment: @Elltz what setup pages?